Running angular project deletes .angular/cache files which for some reason are being detected by .gitignore but shouldn't be
When I run the project on my local machine with 'npm start' it deletes 1459 files from .angular/cache folder and all those changes are being detected in github even though in the ignore file I have .angular/*
Does anyone know how to resolve this?
I am not allowed to push anything. I can potentially commit the files being deleted but I am afraid that I will accidentally push the change.
So far my workaround is to start the project and discard all the changes and then start my work on the project and hope that I can finish whatever I started by the end of my shift.
node.js version 14.20.0
npm version 6.14.17
angular/cli version 14.2.12
These are the versions that I have to use for the project so upgrading/downgrading does not really help.
I tried deleting the whole project from my machine, deleting github, removing angular and node.js.
Cleared cache and registry and rebooted my laptop. Then re-installed everything but the issue stays, which makes me think that my github user is somehow messed up, not sure if this is possible.
The seniors that that tried to help me with this asked me to remove the node_modules folder and the .angular folder.
Then run the 'npm install' in the project folder and run the project with 'npm start', which has absolutely no effect.
Tried to add also the .angular/cache/* folder
Tried to add all the files from the github desktop to the ignore file, but that does not work as well, they are still showing as changes.

If you want to ignore .angular and its sub directories, you should just write .angular/ in .gitignore.

I have the .angular/ in the gitignore and for some reason it does still detect the changes.
